# accept(2) without listen(2)

Tags: linux, sockets

I was wondering, is there a way to accept a connection without listening to it first?
Alternatively, is there a way to reuse the listening socket as the accepted socket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No and no.

The socket isn't put into listening mode until you call `listen()`. It must be listening in order to `accept()`. And, once you're listening, you cannot convert the socket to a connected socket. You *can* close the listening socket and use `dup2` to "rename" the connected socket fd to what the listening socket used - but I think you should reconsider your design if you need this.

Answer (score 0):

No, not in the socket API. Unless dup2 to copy the accepted socket to the number of the listening socket would do you good.

```
 that is

 f1 = socket
 listen(f1
 f2 = accept(f1
 dup2(f2, f1)
 close(f2)
```

to discard the listening socket and use its number for the accepted connection.